# How long can french buttercream last in the fridge/freezer?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, storage-lifetime

French buttercream contains egg yolks that have been cooked via hot liquid sugar water. How long can I safely store this in an airtight container at 0ºC?

Answer (score 1):

According to a recipe from [Serious Eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2017/11/french-vanilla-buttercream-frosting-recipe.html), French buttercream can be refrigerated for up to 2 weeks and frozen for up to several months. For the best texture, warm to 72°F and re-whip in a stand mixer before use.

This is slightly at odds with the [FDA recommendations](https://www.fda.gov/food/buy-store-serve-safe-food/what-you-need-know-about-egg-safety) suggesting that cooked egg dishes be refrigerated and used within 3-4 days. It is possible that something else in the buttercream inhibits microbial growth, allowing longer storage, but I don't want to speculate. To be conservative, you should follow the FDA guideline or freeze immediately.

Comment: The high-sugar and low-moisture environment is what inhibits bacterial growth. That's why it's safe to use on cakes which will be served and kept at room temperature for several days. (Not gonna lie, I will sooner microwave cake than eat cold frosting. If you're going to serve it out of the fridge, please stick to whipped cream...! T.T)